How do Thomists respond to the medical condition of aphantasia?
In Thomistic epistemology having phantasms in the mind is central, out of which the mind extracts a universal, the activity of the active intellect characteristics of rational beings (like us).  But people who has been diagnosed with aphantasia can still do this very fundamental mind activity (such as recognizing the dogness out of instances of dogs that one sees).
On the surface it looks like a counter-example to Thomistic epistemology.  How do modern Thomists tackle the medical condition of aphantasia to preserve the central place of phantasm in human cognition?  It would be great if in addition, the answer can elaborate whether the issue was anticipated by pre-modern Thomists.

The question can be posed to all Aristotelians, not just Thomists, the idea comes from Aristotle himself:"The soul never thinks without a mental image [phantasma]" (De Anima). SEP points out a similar problem:"His suggestions in this direction may seem unfortunate, since for a broad range of thoughts, images, construed naturally and narrowly as pictorial representations, seem unnecessary or even plainly irrelevant". They suggest that his equating of thinking with imagining should be "tempered" and not apply universally.

@Conifold Thanks.  Can I then expect modern Thomists and modern Aristotelians solve the problem similarly, or is there specific element of Thomist epistemology (which probably borrows from Augustine / Neoplatonism or even from Christian theology) influencing Thomistic solution that modern / purist Aristotelians would loath to take?
